# Overlapping geom-coord works for one or the others

Tags: r, overlap, coordinate-transformation, geometry-surface, scatterpie

I am mapping data by using **geom_scatterpie**. However, either my map is skewed, or my pie charts. When using coord_map/coord_fixed, I cannot use these functions separately. How can I make sure both my map and my pie charts look 'normal'?

This is the code I run:

```
ggplot()+ geom_polygon(data = NLD_fixed, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                       fill= 'gray',colour = "white")+ 
                       geom_scatterpie(data=DF,aes(x=V9, y=V8, r=total/150),
                       cols = c("A","B", "C"),
                       alpha=.3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: the goal of my code is to map pie charts for different regions, so that I can see where some technologies are produced, in what quantity, and which (therefore the pie charts). As you can see, my pie charts are skewed. If I use coord_fixed, my base map is skewed.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm41k.png)

```
df<- structure(list(V8 = c(50.85, 51.4478875, 51.45, 51.966667, 52), 
                    V9 = c(5.683333, 5.4859493, 5.466667, 5.666667, 4.366667), 
                    Bio = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), Comp = c(0, 0, 2, 0, 16), 
                    EnConv = c(0, 2, 1, 0, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                    class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                    groups = structure(list(V8 = c(50.85, 51.4478875, 51.45, 51.966667, 52), 
                    .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I have tried the method of a similar question ([R pie charts distorted when adding to projected map using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398344/r-pie-charts-distorted-when-adding-to-projected-map-using-ggplot))
With Step 1:

```
  tidyr::gather(type, value, -V8, -V9, -total,-V10, -City) %>%
  tidyr::nest(type, value)
```

with dataset:

```
structure(list(V8 = c(50.85, 51, 51.44789, 51.45, 51.85, 51.966667, 
52, 52.091, 52.15, 52.216667, 52.25, 52.35, 52.766667, 53.2, 
53.216667), V9 = c(5.683333, 5.766667, 5.866667, 5.466667, 5.75, 
5.666667, 4.366667, 5.122, 4.5, 6.9, 4.716667, 4.916667, 4.666667, 
5.783333, 6.55), City = c("Maastricht", "Urmond", "TU/E", "Eindhoven", 
"Nijmegen", "Wageningen", "Delft", "Utrecht", "Leiden", "Enschede", 
"VU Campus", "Amsterdam", "Petten", "Leeuwarden", "Groningen"
), total = c(8, 23, 79, 93, 16, 53, 69, 85, 26, 23, 33, 52, 21, 
19, 27), V10 = c(50.81, 50.96, 51.40789, 51.41, 51.81, 51.926667, 
51.96, 52.051, 52.11, 52.176667, 52.21, 52.31, 52.726667, 53.16, 
53.176667), data = list(structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(
    type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(5, 
    15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(7, 17, 13, 28, 1, 11, 
1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H"), value = c(12, 6, 10, 47, 0, 15, 0, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(
    type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(0, 
    3, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(2, 28, 10, 4, 0, 1, 
0, 8)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H"), value = c(16, 13, 4, 23, 1, 7, 4, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(
    type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(3, 
    36, 7, 33, 1, 3, 0, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(0, 10, 5, 11, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H"), value = c(5, 9, 2, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(
    type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(4, 
    3, 9, 15, 0, 1, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(7, 10, 11, 18, 1, 4, 
1, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H"), value = c(3, 11, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(
    type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(1, 
    15, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L)), structure(list(type = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), value = c(2, 11, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 
2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)))), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(V8 = c(50.85, 
51, 51.44789, 51.45, 51.85, 51.966667, 52, 52.091, 52.15, 52.216667, 
52.25, 52.35, 52.766667, 53.2, 53.216667), V9 = c(5.683333, 5.766667, 
5.866667, 5.466667, 5.75, 5.666667, 4.366667, 5.122, 4.5, 6.9, 
4.716667, 4.916667, 4.666667, 5.783333, 6.55), .rows = list(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = FALSE))
```

(Warning message:
All elements of '...' must be named.
Did you want `data = c(type, value)`? )

but when I try step 2 (added to my dataset)

```
mutate(pie.grob = purrr::map(data,
                               function(d) ggplotGrob(ggplot(d, 
                                                             aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = type)) +
                                                        geom_col(color = "black",
                                                                 show.legend = FALSE) +
                                                        coord_polar(theta = "y") +
                                                        theme_void())))
```

I get the error: Error: .x must be a vector, not a function
I've tried playing around with the first code, and with the second, but cannot seem to get it right.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. What is your code expected to do? What does "charts look 'normal'" mean to you. Maybe you add some images of your plots and describe what's wrong with them and, most importantly provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to clarify my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R pie charts distorted when adding to projected map using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398344/r-pie-charts-distorted-when-adding-to-projected-map-using-ggplot)

Comment: I have tried it, but run into trouble in step 2: for which the purrr function returns: Error: `.x` must be a vector, not a function

Comment: Then edit your question and paste that code you've Problems with.